# Firebase node deletion not working Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a for loop of dataSnaphots like this:

```
for (final DataSnapshot advertiser : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
```

and I have a button called 'delete' which has to delete a node in my database (code placed inside the for loop)

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                        .setTitle("Delete service")
                                        .setMessage("Do you want to delete this service?")
                                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                databaseReference.child(advertiser.getKey()).removeValue()
                                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                            ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Deleting service...", true);
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Service deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }
                                        }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
                            }
                        });
```

the toast to confirm the deletion is appearing but the node still remains in my database

here's my database:

[image]

Comment: do you set the correct permission to this ?

Comment: what permission?

Comment: In a default configuration unauthenticated users cannot write to the database. To detect this, attach an error listener as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201703212023304320103

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my app requires login to be able to use it; so the users are already authenticated

Comment: Wild guess. If your `databaseReference` is `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`, then you should use this code: `databaseReference.child("Advertiser").child(advertiser.getKey()).removeValue()`

Comment: @koceeng this is exactly what I needed! Please put it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare `databaseReference` as `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`, then it will point to root data of your database. And from your code, I see:

```
databaseReference.child(advertiser.getKey()).removeValue();
```

That will remove value on `your-database-root/(advertiserkey)`. But from your database structure screenshot, I realize you want to delete data on `your-database-root\Advertiser\(advertiserkey)`. So your code should look like this:

```
databaseReference.child("Advertiser").child(advertiser.getKey()).removeValue();
```

And that should do